# How to prove these two elements are conjugate?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

This is a problem from S.-T. Yau College Student Mathematics Contests 2019.

Let $G$ be a finite group. Assume that for any representation $V$ of $G$ over a field of characteristic zero, the character $\chi_{V}$ takes value in $\mathbb{Q}$. Assume $g$ is an element in $G$ such that $g^{2019}=1$. Prove that $g$ and $g^{19}$ are conjugate in $G$.

Here is what I have got:

1. Since $\chi_V$ is an algebraic integer, we can deduce $\chi_V$ takes value in $\mathbb{Z}$.
2. To prove $g$ and $g^{19}$ are conjugate in $G$, it suffices to show $\chi_V(g)=\chi_V(g^{19})$ for any irreducible representation $V$, because any class functions of $G$ is a linear combination of $\chi_V$ where $V$ is irreducible.

I know the fact that $\chi_V$ takes value in $\mathbb{Z}$ plays an important role in this problem. But I don't know how to use it. I hope someone may help me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Gal}{Gal}$$\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}$Let $\omega$ be a $2019$-th primitive root of $1$. Since $19$ and $2019$ are coprime, $\omega^{19}$ is also such a primitive root, so that $\omega \mapsto \omega^{19}$ yields an element $\alpha \in \Gal(\Q(\omega)/\Q)$.

Fix an irreducible character $\chi$ of $G$, and let $\rho$ be a corresponding representation. Then we know that, with respect to a suitable basis, $\rho(g)$ is a diagonal matrix, with diagonal entries $\omega^{a_{1}}, \omega^{a_{2}}, \dots$, for suitable $a_{1}, a_{2}, \dots$.

Thus $\rho(g^{19}) = \rho(g)^{19}$ is also diagonal, with diagonal entries $\omega^{19 a_{1}}, \omega^{19 a_{2}}, \dots$

It follows that
$$
\chi(g) = \omega^{a_{1}} + \omega^{a_{2}} + \dots,
$$
and
$$
\chi(g^{19}) = \omega^{19 a_{1}} + \omega^{19 a_{2}} + \dots,
$$
so that $\chi(g^{19}) = \chi(g)^{\alpha} = \chi(g)$, as $\chi(g) \in \Q$.

Comment: I would point out that the result that any two primitive complex $n$th roots of $1$ are equivlaent under a field automorphism of the cyclotomic field is highly nontrivial! It is essentially equivalent to the irreducibility of the cyclotomic polynomials over ${\mathbb Q}$, which is a double-starred exercise in Herstein's Topics in Algebra.

Comment: @DerekHolt, I agree, of course. Jacobson and Lang indeed give a proof.

Comment: Excellent answer! Thanks!